# Why tsconfig.spec.json is using CommonJs in Angular Cli?

Tags: angular

I was just checking the files generated by angular cli. I noticed that tsconfig.spec.json is using commonJs as module, and tsconfig.app.json is using es2015 as module.

Is there any reason for choosing different module implementations?

Angular CLI version: 1.1.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982786/angular-cli-and-multiple-configuration-files I think 'commonjs' is better for server side and 'es2015' is better for application side.

Answer (score 1):

tsconfig.spec.json is used for testing, which runs in node.js environment, while tsconfig.app.json is being used to prepare the app for browser based run, hence the different moduling implementations.